# Using Ruby on rails Form to pass Username and Password to Joomla Login Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, joomla2.5

i am trying create a form in a Ruby on Rails application, which will send the username and password from my database to Joomla Admin Login.
I can't find the right method the controller of the model needs.

A second thought is to use Javascript but i don't know the way. I found some code, but i would like some explanations about this. I should write it straight to html.erb file or somewhere else?

I tryed to do it by creating a form in my show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for myproject,  url: myproject.admin_url, method: :get do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :mod_login_username_lbl, name: myproject.project_user, 
value::get%>
<%= f.hidden_field :mod_login_password_lbl, name: myproject.project_pwd, 
value: :get %>
<%= f.button "Log in", :button_html => {:class => "btn primary", 
:onclick =>"this.form.submit();" }%>
<% end %>
```

The resault is that, i can see the url at the browser that shows the username and the password but i want to know how to enter them to joomla form and submit to login.

**http://www.myjoomla.gr/final_project/administrator/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&admin=get&123456=get&button=**

I am using "get" method, because "put" did not do anything.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you want to create some form that sends the form data to the joomla login or do you want to write some code that simulates a webbrowser to verify a user/pass by loging into an existing joomla?

Comment: Hi, i have a model. Some of his attributes are the username and the password of the joomla backend of an already installed joomla. I want a form with hidden fields, which when i click on the submit button to fill the joomla login and login joomla administration page.